# Two or more UpdateView in one view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have too many forms, more than 60 i think, each form is a model from ModelForm, the user may be able to update the data the they fill, im doing it with an UpdateView for each form, i mean, one view for each form so i have too many views, maybe following the philosophy of django "don't repeat yourself" can i have just one view and one template for update all the forms?

Operation is the following:

Each form is a model, and each form has an unique URL, so django has to detect which update form has to render depending of the pk pass it to the URL. Until here I did it but as I told before, each view for each form, I need to do it in one view for all forms using one template.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass options to the view class in your url configuration:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', UpdateView.as_view(model=MyModel, form_class=MyModelForm))
]
```

These options can be any attribute that exists on the view class, and will overwrite the value for that instance.

Comment: thanks, thats works.. But is there some way to pass an unique template for all the url that renders only one form depending the parameters?

Comment: `template_name` is another option you can pass this way.

Comment: nice! i thought that only one template can be passed to one view